# Async task deadlocks if task is extracted first

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, deadlock

I'm using Microsoft's `AsyncHelper` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs)) to call an async method from a synchronous context. This works just fine:

```
Result r = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync());
```

However, if I extract the Task and then try to run this extracted task synchronously instead, I encounter a deadlock.:

```
Task<Result> t = SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync();
Result r = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await t);
```

Why does this happen, and what can be done to make this run?

Comment: Notice how `AsyncHelper.RunSync` is running `SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync` by calling `_myTaskFactory.StartNew`. This makes sure that there's no SynchronziationContext installed on the thread which starts executing `SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync`. Indeed, `AsyncHelper.RunSync` works *because* it calls `SomeMethodAsync` on a thread with no `SynchronizationContext` installed on it. The way to avoid this is to make sure that `SomeMethodAsync` is called on a thread without a `SynchronizationContext` on it, by using something like `AsyncHelper.RunAsync`...

Comment: This looks a lot like "sync over async", in which case yes: this is a very well-known problem, which is exactly *why* you're not meant to do "sync over async". Ultimately, you can't go **slightly** async; you need to go async all the way. The only **supported** answer to the question, then, is to remove the sync-over-async: `Result r = await SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync();` (and make the code path you're working on `async` / `[ValueTask][<T>]`-based)

Answer (score 3):

`AsyncHelper.RunSync` uses the [thread pool hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) to ensure that its delegate is called without a context, thus making it safe to block on (assuming that the delegate is safe to be called on a thread pool thread). In your code, `SomeMethodAsync` is executed on a thread pool thread, so any `await`s will not [capture a context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

> what can be done to make this run?

Well, you would use the first code sample instead of the second.

If you want to have a construct that represents some code to run, then you should use a delegate type such as `Func<Task<T>>`. E.g.:

```
Func<Task<Result>> func = () => SomeClass.SomeMethodAsync();
Result r = AsyncHelper.RunSync(func);
```

With asynchronous code, `Task<T>` does not represent some code to run; it represents some code that *has already started*. Use `Func<Task<T>>` to represent some code to run.